# Scammed on Facebook advertising, where to report? How to report that to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

Last day my girlfriend was scammed by a Facebook ad, the ad was on a boots shop which had a fake login page etc. So basically that scam site got my credit card number. The alarm to me was the fact the site was not allowing her to login (email not existing), then I checked and it was registered domain just few days ago, and there was no HTTPS at all, so I realized that is a scam and she will not receive any boots.

**How can I report that to Facebook?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/181495968648557?helpref=faq_content):

**How to Report Things**

> **Ads**
>
> > To report an ad:
> >
> > 1. Hover over the ad and click the **X** in the top right
> > 2. Choose **Hide ad** to report a specific ad, or **Hide all from...** to hide all ads from that particular advertiser

---

> **Something I Can't See**
>
> > If you can't report something on Facebook because you don't have a Facebook account or you can't see whatever you're trying to report, please use a computer to [fill out this form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/274459462613911).

In your case you can report the ad if you are still seeing that and fill out the form given in above link by selecting ***Other abuse*** option and give the complete details to them. Hopefully they will come back to you.

If you have received any email, you can forward it to `phish@fb.com`.

Comment: As I sad in the question my girl was scammed few days ago, there's no longer any ad to report. I'll ask her to fill the form "other abuse"